# JsonConvert.PopulateObject() is not handling the decimal type data properly

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON string:

```
{"PaymentVoucherNumber":15,"PaymentVoucherDate":"2019-09-10T00:00:00","pvExpiryDate":"2019-09-22T00:00:00","Amount":35.000,"ReceiptNumber":0}
```

In this json the `Amount` is a double value.

```
public partial class VoucherList 
{
    [JsonProperty("PaymentVoucherNumber")]
    public long PaymentVoucherNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PaymentVoucherDate")]
    public string PaymentVoucherDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pvExpiryDate")]
    public string PvExpiryDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Amount")]
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ReceiptNumber")]
    public long ReceiptNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I have used JsonConvert.PopulateObject(). But in the result, the amount field is coming as decimal part removed.ie just 35

```
VoucherList pv=new VoucherList();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json,pv);
```

Please advice...

Comment: Have you tried with a decimal number having the decimal part different from X.0? For example with 35.2 instead of 35.0 It should keep the decimal number.

Comment: Your data model doesn't have any `decimal` properties, it has `double`.  `double` doesn't store a number of digits; `decimal` [does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, in your data model, you are using `double` and not `decimal` for `Amount`:

```
[JsonProperty("Amount")]
public double Amount { get; set; }
```

You need to change that to `decimal`:

```
[JsonProperty("Amount")]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

When you do, the number of decimal digits in the JSON will be remembered in the `decimal` struct.  This is possible because, as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> A decimal number is a floating-point value that consists of a sign, a numeric value where each digit in the value ranges from 0 to 9, and a scaling factor that indicates the position of a floating decimal point that separates the integral and fractional parts of the numeric value. ...
>
> The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.

No such capability is present for [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) which is a purely IEEE 754 binary floating-point representation and thus *cannot* distinguish between `35`, `35.0` or `35.0000`.  As a result, when you inspect `pv.Amount` after population, `35` is shown for the `35.0` JSON value.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aq9Pj6).