# Json.Net not serializing decimals the same way twice

Tags: c#, json.net, decimal

I was testing Json.NET serialization of a shopping cart I'm working on and noticed that when I serialize -> deserialize -> serialize again, I'm getting a difference in the trailing zero formatting of some of the `decimal` fields. Here is the serialization code:

```
private static void TestRoundTripCartSerialization(Cart cart)
{
    string cartJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(cartJson);

    Cart cartClone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cart>(cartJson);

    string cloneJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cartClone, Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(cloneJson);

    Console.WriteLine("\r\n Serialized carts are " + (cartJson == cloneJson ? "" : "not") + " identical");
}
```

The `Cart` implements `IEnumerable<T>` and has a `JsonObjectAttribute` to allow it to serialize as an object, including its properties as well as its inner list. The `decimal` properties of `Cart` do not change, but some of the `decimal` properties of objects and their inner objects in the inner list/array do as in this excerpt from output of the code above:

First time serializing:

```
      ...
      "Total": 27.0000,
      "PaymentPlan": {
        "TaxRate": 8.00000,
        "ManualDiscountApplied": 0.0,
        "AdditionalCashDiscountApplied": 0.0,
        "PreTaxDeposit": 25.0000,
        "PreTaxBalance": 0.0,
        "DepositTax": 2.00,
        "BalanceTax": 0.0,
        "SNPFee": 25.0000,
        "cartItemPaymentPlanTypeID": "SNP",
        "unitPreTaxTotal": 25.0000,
        "unitTax": 2.00
      }
    }
  ],
 }
```

Second time serializing:

```
      ...
      "Total": 27.0,
      "PaymentPlan": {
        "TaxRate": 8.0,
        "ManualDiscountApplied": 0.0,
        "AdditionalCashDiscountApplied": 0.0,
        "PreTaxDeposit": 25.0,
        "PreTaxBalance": 0.0,
        "DepositTax": 2.0,
        "BalanceTax": 0.0,
        "SNPFee": 25.0,
        "cartItemPaymentPlanTypeID": "SNP",
        "unitPreTaxTotal": 25.0,
        "unitTax": 2.0
      }
    }
  ],
 }
```

Notice the `Total`, `TaxRate`, and some of the others have changed from four trailing zeroes to a single trailing zero. I did find some stuff regarding changes to handling of trailing zeroes in the source code at one point, but nothing that I understood well enough to put together with this. I can't share the full Cart implementation here, but I built a bare bones model of it and couldn't reproduce the results. The most obvious differences were my bare bones version lost some additional inheritance/implementation of abstract base classes and interfaces and some generic type usage on those (where the generic type param defines the type of some of the nested child objects).

So I'm hoping without that someone can still answer: Any idea why the trailing zeroes change? The objects appear to be identical to the original after deserializing either JSON string, but I want to be sure there isn't something in Json.NET that causes a loss of precision or rounding that may gradually change one of these decimals after many serialization round trips.

---

**Updated**

Here's a reproducible example. I thought I had ruled out the `JsonConverter` but was mistaken. Because my inner `_items` list is typed on an interface, I have to tell Json.NET which concrete type to deserialize back to. I didn't want the actual `Type` names in the JSON so rather than using `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, I've given the items a unique string identifier property. The `JsonConverter` uses that to choose a concrete type to create, but I guess the `JObject` has already parsed my `decimal`s to `double`s? This is maybe my 2nd time implementing a `JsonConverter` and I don't have a complete understanding of how they work because finding documentation has been difficult. So I may have `ReadJson` all wrong.

```
[JsonObject]
public class Test : IEnumerable<IItem>
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TestItemJsonConverter))]
    protected List<IItem> _items;

    public Test() { }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Test(IEnumerable<IItem> o)
    {
        _items = o == null ? new List<IItem>() : new List<IItem>(o);
    }

    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<IItem> IEnumerable<IItem>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}

public interface IItem
{
    string ItemName { get; }
}

public class Item1 : IItem
{
    public Item1() { }
    public Item1(decimal fee) { Fee = fee; }

    public string ItemName { get { return "Item1"; } }

    public virtual decimal Fee { get; set; }
}

public class TestItemJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return (objectType == typeof(IItem)); }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object result = null;

        JObject jObj = JObject.Load(reader);

        string itemTypeID = jObj["ItemName"].Value<string>();

        //NOTE: My real implementation doesn't have hard coded strings or types here.
        //See the code block below for actual implementation.
        if (itemTypeID == "Item1")
            result = jObj.ToObject(typeof(Item1), serializer);

        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test test1 = new Test(new List<Item1> { new Item1(9.00m), new Item1(24.0000m) })
        {
            Total = 33.0000m
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Test test1Clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
        string json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1Clone, Formatting.Indented);
        Console.WriteLine(json2);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Snippet from my actual converter:

```
if (CartItemTypes.TypeMaps.ContainsKey(itemTypeID))
    result = jObj.ToObject(CartItemTypes.TypeMaps[itemTypeID], serializer);
```

Comment: One possibility is that you are using `double` not `decimal` in your data model.  See: [JsonConvert.PopulateObject() is not handling the decimal type data properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57867427/3744182).

Comment: Another possibility is that, somewhere in your code, you have a `JsonConverter` that preloads the JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy, at which point the JSON floating point values are deserialized to an intermediate `double`.  To avoid this you need to set `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` in the converter or at some higher level, see [Force decimal type in class definition during serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180588/3744182).  But we need to see a [mcve] to be sure I reckon.

Comment: Surprised you got any trailing decimals in the first place since trailing and leading zero is strictly a string thing, except where you need a .0 after the whole number to distinguish a decimal or float literal from an integer literal

Comment: @mlibby - actually `decimal` preserves information about trailing zeros, see he [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netframework-4.8#remarks): *The scaling factor also preserves any trailing zeros in a Decimal number. Trailing zeros do not affect the value of a Decimal number in arithmetic or comparison operations. However, trailing zeros might be revealed by the ToString method if an appropriate format string is applied.*  And Json.NET will preserve trailing zeros for `decimal`, see e.g. https://dotnetfiddle.net/KqfGSR

Comment: @dbc Perfect, you got it! I am using a `JsonConverter` which was where I suspected the problem was, but wasn't able to reproduce it. Turned out my converter was not being executed and I had not explicitly defined extra 0s on my values. Sometimes including a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) isn't easy until you have an idea where the problem lies so thanks for your effort and not just down voting or voting to close. I've updated the question with that. I understand your problem but am not sure I understand your solution yet.

Comment: @dbc I guess part of what I don't understand is of what value the default `Double` setting is. Wouldn't it have been better to have `Decimal` be the default so as to not accidentally lose precision? And what is the effect changing this to `Decimal` if my `IItem` were to also contain a `double` typed field? It seems like it should need to be set on a property by property basis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your polymorphic models contain `decimal` properties, in order not to lose precision, you must temporarily set [`JsonReader.FloatParseHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_FloatParseHandling.htm) to be [`FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) when pre-loading your JSON into a `JToken` hierarchy, like so:

```
public class TestItemJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object result = null;

        var old = reader.FloatParseHandling;
        try
        {
            reader.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;

            JObject jObj = JObject.Load(reader);
            string itemTypeID = jObj["ItemName"].Value<string>();

            //NOTE: My real implementation doesn't have hard coded strings or types here.
            //See the code block below for actual implementation.
            if (itemTypeID == "Item1")
                result = jObj.ToObject(typeof(Item1), serializer);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.FloatParseHandling = old;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Nh7rYF).

Why is this necessary?  As it turns out, you have encountered an unfortunate design decision in Json.NET.  When [`JsonTextReader`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) encounters a floating-point value, it parses it to either `decimal` or `double` as defined by the above-mentioned `FloatParseHandling` setting.    Once the choice is made, the JSON value is parsed into the target type and stored in [`JsonReader.Value`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Value.htm), and the underlying character sequence is discarded.  Thus, if a poor choice of floating-point type is made, it's difficult to correct the mistake later on.

So, ideally we would like to choose as a default floating-point type the "most general" floating point type, one that can be converted to all others without loss of information.  Unfortunately, in .Net **no such type exists**.  The possibilities are summarized in *[Characteristics of the floating-point types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#characteristics-of-the-floating-point-types)*:

[image: Characteristics of the floating-point types]

As you can see, `double` supports a larger range while `decimal` supports a larger precision.  As such, to minimize data loss, sometimes `decimal` would need to be chosen, and sometimes `double`.  And, again unfortunately, no such logic is built into `JsonReader`; there is no `FloatParseHandling.Auto` option to choose the most appropriate representation.

In the absence of such an option or the ability to load the original floating-point value as a string and re-parse it later, you will need to hardcode your converter with an appropriate `FloatParseHandling` setting based upon your data model(s) when you pre-load your `JToken` hierarchy.

In cases where your data models contain both `double` and `decimal` members, pre-loading using `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` will likely meet your needs, because Json.NET will throw a `JsonReaderException` when attempting to deserialize a too-large value into a `decimal` (demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rcVxDw)) but will silently round the value off when attempting to deserialize a too-precise value into a `double`.  Practically speaking, it's unlikely you will have floating-point values larger than `10^28` with more than 15 digits of precision + trailing zeros in the same polymorphic data model.  In the unlikely chance you do, by using `FloatParseHandling.Decimal` you'll get an explicit exception explaining the problem.

Notes:

- I don't know why `double` was chosen instead of `decimal` as the "default default" floating point format.  Json.NET was originally released in [2006](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2006/06/26/Json.NET-Simplifying-.NET-JavaScript-communication); my recollection is that `decimal` wasn't widely used back then, so maybe this is a legacy choice that was never revisited?
- When deserializing directly to a `decimal` or `double` member, the serializer will override the default floating-point type by calling [`ReadAsDouble()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_ReadAsDouble.htm) or [`ReadAsDecimal()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_ReadAsDecimal.htm), so precision is not lost when deserializing directly from a JSON string.  The problem only arises when pre-loading into a `JToken` hierarchy then subsequently deserializing.
- [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=netcore-3.1) and [`JsonElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1) from [system.text.json](/questions/tagged/system.text.json), Microsoft's replacement for Json.NET in .NET Core 3.0, avoid this problem by always maintaining the underlying byte sequence of a floating-point JSON value, which is one example of the new API being an improvement on the old.

  If you actually have values larger than `10^28` with more than 15 digits of precision + trailing zeros in the same polymorphic data model, switching to this new serializer might be a valid option.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've read in a while, thanks! This solves my problem, but where it seems to leave a hole is, since you have to apply the converter to the parent property/container, you could run into a problem where you need both `Double` and `Decimal`. E.g. if `IItem` had an additional `double Number` property, both `Fee` and `Number` will be parsed as either a `double` or `decimal`. So you could end up having to choose between either a loss of precision or an out of range value if I'm understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.  But in reality, what are the chance you are going to have values larger than `10^28` with more than 15 digits of precision + trailing zeros in the same polymorphic data model?  Chances are you can choose one or the other and things will just work since it's unlikely you will have values that large and also that precise.  But it not it may be time to look into `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, it solves my problem. Just making sure I'm understand it. `System.Text.Json`'s approach sounds better and I can't wait to start using .NET Core in general. Unfortunately we haven't quite gotten there yet.