# What is equivalent in JToken.DeepEquals in System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, json.net, system.text.json

I want to migrate my code from Newtonsoft Json.Net to Microsoft standard System.Text.Json. But I could not find an alternative for `JToken.DeepEqual`

Basically the code must compare two JSON in unit test. Reference JSON, and Result JSON.  I used the mechanism in Newtonsoft to create two `JObject` and then compare them with `JToken.DeepEqual`. Here is the example code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExampleUnitTes()
{
    string resultJson = TestedUnit.TestedMethod();
    string referenceJson =
    @"
    {
      ...bla bla bla...
      ...some JSON Content...
      ...bla bla bla...
    }";

    JObject expected = ( JObject )JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( referenceJson );
    JObject result = ( JObject )JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( resultJson );
    Assert.IsTrue( JToken.DeepEquals( result, expected ) );
}
```

If I am correct the Newtonsoft `JObject` similar in `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument`, and I am able to create it, just I don't know how to compare the contents of it.

```cs
System.Text.Json.JsonDocument expectedDoc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse( referenceJson );
System.Text.Json.JsonDocument resultDoc = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse( json );

Compare???( expectedDoc, resulDoc );
```

Of course, string compare is not a solution, because the format of the JSON doesn't matter and the order of the properties also doesn't matter.

Comment: You can refer to [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to), if there is nothing helpful, you should write it by yourself, I don't think that exists from the box for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since version **1.3.0** of my [`SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch/) NuGet package, you can use [`DeepEquals` extension method](https://github.com/weichch/system-text-json-jsondiffpatch#deepequals) to compare `JsonDocument`, `JsonElement` and `JsonNode`.

**Original Answer Below**

For the [System.Text.Json.Nodes namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsonnode) introduced since .NET 6 release, there is currently a [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/56592) to discuss adding `DeepEquals` functionality to `JsonNode`.

I rolled my own implementation of `DeepEquals` as part of my [`SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SystemTextJson.JsonDiffPatch/) NuGet package. By default, the extension compares raw text of JSON values, which is not what `JToken.DeepEquals` does. Semantic equality needs to be enabled as:

```
var node1 = JsonNode.Parse("[1.0]");
var node2 = JsonNode.Parse("[1]");

// false
bool equal = node1.DeepEquals(node2);
// true
bool semanticEqual = node1.DeepEquals(node2, JsonElementComparison.Semantic);
```

Comment: Thanks!   I need both DeepEquals() and DeepClone().

Answer (score 18):

There is no equivalent in [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.1) as of .Net 3.1, so we will have to roll our own.  Here's one possible `IEqualityComparer<JsonElement>`:

```
public class JsonElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<JsonElement>
{
    public JsonElementComparer() : this(-1) { }

    public JsonElementComparer(int maxHashDepth) => this.MaxHashDepth = maxHashDepth;

    int MaxHashDepth { get; } = -1;

    #region IEqualityComparer<JsonElement> Members

    public bool Equals(JsonElement x, JsonElement y)
    {
        if (x.ValueKind != y.ValueKind)
            return false;
        switch (x.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Null:
            case JsonValueKind.True:
            case JsonValueKind.False:
            case JsonValueKind.Undefined:
                return true;
                
            // Compare the raw values of numbers, and the text of strings.
            // Note this means that 0.0 will differ from 0.00 -- which may be correct as deserializing either to `decimal` will result in subtly different results.
            // Newtonsoft's JValue.Compare(JTokenType valueType, object? objA, object? objB) has logic for detecting "equivalent" values, 
            // you may want to examine it to see if anything there is required here.
            // https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs#L246
            case JsonValueKind.Number:
                return x.GetRawText() == y.GetRawText();

            case JsonValueKind.String:
                return x.GetString() == y.GetString(); // Do not use GetRawText() here, it does not automatically resolve JSON escape sequences to their corresponding characters.
                
            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                return x.EnumerateArray().SequenceEqual(y.EnumerateArray(), this);
            
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                {
                    // Surprisingly, JsonDocument fully supports duplicate property names.
                    // I.e. it's perfectly happy to parse {"Value":"a", "Value" : "b"} and will store both
                    // key/value pairs inside the document!
                    // A close reading of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4 seems to indicate that
                    // such objects are allowed but not recommended, and when they arise, interpretation of 
                    // identically-named properties is order-dependent.  
                    // So stably sorting by name then comparing values seems the way to go.
                    var xPropertiesUnsorted = x.EnumerateObject().ToList();
                    var yPropertiesUnsorted = y.EnumerateObject().ToList();
                    if (xPropertiesUnsorted.Count != yPropertiesUnsorted.Count)
                        return false;
                    var xProperties = xPropertiesUnsorted.OrderBy(p => p.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal);
                    var yProperties = yPropertiesUnsorted.OrderBy(p => p.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal);
                    foreach (var (px, py) in xProperties.Zip(yProperties))
                    {
                        if (px.Name != py.Name)
                            return false;
                        if (!Equals(px.Value, py.Value))
                            return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                
            default:
                throw new JsonException(string.Format("Unknown JsonValueKind {0}", x.ValueKind));
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(JsonElement obj)
    {
        var hash = new HashCode(); // New in .Net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode
        ComputeHashCode(obj, ref hash, 0);
        return hash.ToHashCode();
    }

    void ComputeHashCode(JsonElement obj, ref HashCode hash, int depth)
    {
        hash.Add(obj.ValueKind);

        switch (obj.ValueKind)
        {
            case JsonValueKind.Null:
            case JsonValueKind.True:
            case JsonValueKind.False:
            case JsonValueKind.Undefined:
                break;
                
            case JsonValueKind.Number:
                hash.Add(obj.GetRawText());
                break;

            case JsonValueKind.String:
                hash.Add(obj.GetString());
                break;
                
            case JsonValueKind.Array:
                if (depth != MaxHashDepth)
                    foreach (var item in obj.EnumerateArray())
                        ComputeHashCode(item, ref hash, depth+1);
                else
                    hash.Add(obj.GetArrayLength());
                break;
            
            case JsonValueKind.Object:
                foreach (var property in obj.EnumerateObject().OrderBy(p => p.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal))
                {
                    hash.Add(property.Name);
                    if (depth != MaxHashDepth)
                        ComputeHashCode(property.Value, ref hash, depth+1);
                }
                break;
                
            default:
                throw new JsonException(string.Format("Unknown JsonValueKind {0}", obj.ValueKind));
        }            
    }
    
    #endregion
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
var comparer = new JsonElementComparer();
using var doc1 = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(referenceJson);
using var doc2 = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(resultJson);
Assert.IsTrue(comparer.Equals(doc1.RootElement, doc2.RootElement));
```

Notes:

- Since Json.NET resolves floating-point JSON values to `double` or `decimal` during parsing, `JToken.DeepEquals()` considers floating-point values that differ only in trailing zeros to be identical.  I.e. the following assertion passes:

  ```
  Assert.IsTrue(JToken.DeepEquals(JToken.Parse("1.0"), JToken.Parse("1.00")));
  ```

  My comparer does **not** consider these two be equal.  I consider this to be desirable because applications sometimes want to preserve trailing zeros, e.g. when deserializing to `decimal`, and thus this difference may sometimes matter.  (For an example see e.g. *[Json.Net not serializing decimals the same way twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60443818/3744182*.))  If you want to consider such JSON values to be identical, you will need to modify the cases for `JsonValueKind.Number` in `ComputeHashCode()` and `Equals(JsonElement x, JsonElement y)` to trim trailing zeros when present after a decimal point.
- Making the above harder is the fact that, surprisingly, `JsonDocument` fully supports duplicate property names!   I.e. it's perfectly happy to parse `{"Value":"a", "Value" : "b"}` and will store both key/value pairs inside the document.

  A close reading of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4 seems to indicate that such objects are allowed but not recommended, and when they arise, interpretation of identically-named properties may be order-dependent.  I handled this by stably sorting the property lists by property name, then walking the lists and comparing names and values.  If you don't care about duplicate property names, you could probably improve the performance by using single lookup dictionary instead of two sorted lists.
- `JsonDocument` is disposable, and in fact needs to be disposed of according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=netcore-3.0#remarks):

  > This class utilizes resources from pooled memory to minimize the impact of the garbage collector (GC) in high-usage scenarios. Failure to properly dispose this object will result in the memory not being returned to the pool, which will increase GC impact across various parts of the framework.

  In your question you do not do this, but you should.
- There is currently an open enhancement *[System.Text.Json: add ability to do semantic comparisons of JSON values à la JToken.DeepEquals() #33388](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/33388)*, to which the development team replied, "this isn't on our roadmap right now."

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ijrDBZ).

Comment: Excelent answer, that is what I need. Thank you very much, the using also

Comment: @dbc, would you mind if I pulled this into my [Json.More](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Json.More.Net/) package? I have an implementation; the Equals is similar, but I like the GetHashCode.  I'll be sure to keep a link to this in the source for credit.

Comment: @gregsdennis - sure, go ahead, I'm flattered.  Please do attribute as per the [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/).

Comment: Added and released, with some modification.  Thanks, and nice work!