# Compare contents of System.Text.JsonDocument C# in unit test

Tags: c#, json

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here... but how can I compare two `JsonDocument`s (or `JsonElement`s or what have you) for JSON equality, i.e. same keys with same values?

To limit the scope, the ability to perform this comparison in a unit test is sufficient unto the day.

I have a unit test in which I want to compare the result of a function that returns a `JsonDocument` to some expected value. Things that don't work include using FluentAssertions.Json (because my type is not `JObject`), and comparing the value of `GetRawText` because I don't care about the whitespace.

I guess I could write the strings out and re-serialize them or something but this honestly feels like such a hack that I must be doing something wrong.

I understand the business logic of comparing them, I have seen the other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580743/what-is-equivalent-in-jtoken-deepequals-in-system-text-json?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65620060/equivalent-of-jobject-in-system-text-json?noredirect=1&lq=1). The first is much more in keeping with what I want, it's just an embarrassing result for C#...
The second is not what I need at all.

Comment: only in the most disappointing sense. I don't have any difficulty understanding the business logic required to perform such a comparison. I just have difficulty understanding how it could be that homerolling the comparison logic is viewed as acceptable by the C# community.

Comment: related: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1212

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking - clearly you are not looking for libraries (off-topic), you claim that essentially identical "deep equal" question is absolutely not what you are looking for... Please [edit] the question to clarify what you hope to see as answer.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen thanks, this looks very promising, and i do appreciate it

Comment: Haven't tried this, but could you `GetHash()` on the `JsonDocument` and then compare hashes?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen your linked issue perfectly solved the problem. If you care to write it up StackOverflow style, I can accept it.

Comment: Here is a library I found that has a `DeepEquals` method for comparing JsonDocument, JsonElement and JsonNode: https://github.com/weichch/system-text-json-jsondiffpatch

Answer (score 1):

### WARNING: Probably not valid

It's been a while and I'm nowhere near that code anymore so I've unaccepted my answer and am editing to include this warning.

I can't swear I checked the negative case, since I don't have access to that code anymore, but on the other hand, as a practice I usually do include both negative and positive tests. That said, multiple users have indicated this approach suffers from systematic Type I errors, so *caveat implementor*!

---

Thanks to @ChristophLütjen for identifying the fix I needed in [this issue](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1212)

Given two `JsonDocument`s I can compare them using FluentAssertions like this:

```
Doc1.RootElement.Should().BeEquivalentTo(Doc2.RootElement, opt => opt.ComparingByMembers<JsonElement>());
```

I'm still bemused that there is not a more straightforward comparison method out there for the general case, but since my immediate use was unit testing, I'm satisfied with this result.

Comment: that didn't work for me.  When testing bad values to ensure the test failed. My test did not fail

Comment: **DO NOT USE THIS!**


it just always returns true. try it yourself on a non-equal documents.

Answer (score 0):

Json.More has a very nice IsEquivalentTo method for comparing System.Text.Json values

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 has a new [`static bool DeepEquals(JsonNode, JsonNode)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.deepequals?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-deepequals(system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode-system-text-json-nodes-jsonnode)) method, if you're just looking for a simple true/false response. Unfortunately, you don't get detailed information about how the two nodes are not equal.

I'd probably start by serializing the documents (with multi-line, indentation) and do a string comparison. That has the advantage that using an assertions library like fluent assertions, you get a nice error message that says something like "{...} does not equal {...}: first difference at line X, character Y".

For anything more specific, you'd probably need to specify options. Should the order of keys be considered important? What about special characters represented different ways in the strings? If an array contains equivalent objects, but at different places, is it still equal? It's not quite as straightforward as it probably seems.