# How to have JsonNode.ToJsonString(...) produce properties in alphabetic order?

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json, jsonnode

I am using [JsonNode.ToJsonString(...)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode.tojsonstring) in my unit tests.
Unfortunately the property order in the serialized string seems to be depend the runtime order how the child nodes and value nodes were added.

However to phrase a unit test expectation the order would be deterministic to allow to be equal to the expectation.

I reviewed the [serializer options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions) but did not find anything related

**Question**

Is there any way to JsonNode.ToJsonString(...) produce properties in alphabetic order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality to do this, however you could create a custom [`JsonConverter<JsonNode>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to) that alphabetizes the properties as they are written.  Then you could serialize your node to JSON using [`JsonSerializer.Serialize(node, options)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=net-7.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-serialize-1(-0-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)) with the converter added to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters).

First, define the following extension method and converter:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    readonly static JsonSerializerOptions defaultOptions = new () { Converters = { AlphabeticJsonNodeConverter.Instance } };
    
    public static string ToAlphabeticJsonString(this JsonNode? node, JsonSerializerOptions? options = default)
    {
        if (options == null)
            options = defaultOptions;
        else
        {
            options = new JsonSerializerOptions(options);
            options.Converters.Insert(0, AlphabeticJsonNodeConverter.Instance);
        }
        return JsonSerializer.Serialize(node, options);
    }
}

public class AlphabeticJsonNodeConverter : JsonConverter<JsonNode>
{
    public static AlphabeticJsonNodeConverter Instance { get; } = new AlphabeticJsonNodeConverter();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(JsonNode).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert) && typeToConvert != typeof(JsonValue);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonNode? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case JsonObject obj:
                writer.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (var pair in obj.OrderBy(p => p.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal))
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName(pair.Key);
                    Write(writer, pair.Value, options);
                }
                writer.WriteEndObject();
                break;
            case JsonArray array: // We need to handle JsonArray explicitly to ensure that objects inside arrays are alphabetized
                writer.WriteStartArray();
                foreach (var item in array)
                    Write(writer, item, options);
                writer.WriteEndArray();
                break;
            case null:
                writer.WriteNullValue();
                break;
            default: // JsonValue
                value.WriteTo(writer, options);
                break;
        }
    }
    
    public override JsonNode? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => JsonNode.Parse(ref reader);
}
```

And now you will be able to do:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true, // Or false, if you prefer
};

var json = node.ToAlphabeticJsonString(options);
```

Notes:

- I used `StringComparer.Ordinal` because it seems to corresponds to the sorting requirement from [RFC 8785: JSON Canonicalization Scheme (JCS)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8785#name-sorting-of-object-propertie).
- While the above converter will work with any `JsonNode` returned from `JsonNode.Parse()`, created from a `JsonElement`, or built up from primitive keys and values as shown in the [doc example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-7-0#create-a-jsonnode-dom-with-object-initializers-and-make-changes), it is also possible to create a `JsonValue` with **any POCO at all** as its value, e.g.:

  ```
  var node = JsonValue.Create(new { ZProperty = "foo", AProperty = "bar" })!;
  ```

  Such cases get formatted to JSON as objects, not a primitive values:

  ```json
  { "ZProperty": "foo", "AProperty": "bar" }
  ```

  I don't know why Microsoft provided such functionality, but when formatting such a node to JSON the code [invokes the serializer](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/614d68307c5b41d1d77a081d747c385b03ac8663/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Nodes/JsonValueNotTrimmable.cs#L23) to serialize its contents.  Thus the converter above will not be invoked to alphabetize properties in such a strange case.
- As an alternative to alphabetizing `JsonNode` properties while writing, you could use `JsonElementComparer` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60592310/3744182) to *[What is equivalent in JToken.DeepEquals in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60580743/3744182)* to compare JSON elements and ignore property order.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lZMUh0).

Comment: many thx for taking time and deep dive into this.